# How to generate editable reference list?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

How to generate an editable numbered reference list according to the style of the manuscript after finish a manuscript?

I know how to generate reference list in manuscript, but how to generate an editable one.

**This is needed, because when submit my manuscript, I find some journals--like some of Elsvier's--ask me to copy my numbered references into a box.**

For now, I just use the "edit pdf" mode of acrobat and copy the reference list piece by piece in the generated manuscript.

Is there a convenient way?

I have searched for "latex editable reference list" in google. No suitable answers are found.

[image: The separated reference list under acrobat "edit pdf" mode]

===========================================================================

**The *.aux file has the orderly citations. Are there some tools that use *.aux, *.bib and .bst to generate a editable numbered reference list in the same style as in the manuscript?**

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way else to achieve this goal? Do I have to pick them up piece by piece from the generated PDF?

Comment: The *.aux file contains the orderly citations. Are there some tools that may use the *.aux, *.bib, and *.bst to generate a editable reference list?

Comment: Do you mean the `*.bbl` file? It contains the complete bibliography enclosed in environment `bibliography` and `\bibitem`. But to be honest, for me is not clear what you mean with "editable reference list". Can you explain better?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I want to generate an editable numbered reference list in the style of the manuscript, so that I can copy and paste the list into a online text box as required by the journals when submitting my manuscript.

Comment: Please give us a link to that journal and the description of that editable list. I fear there is a missunderstanding ...

Comment: Seems like you can just copy-paste from the pdf into the website box? Just by viewing the pdf you can select text with the mouse, right click, press copy, etc.? You can do this one by one but all at the same time is also possible.